# Installing imposm (a Python package) on Mac

Tags: python, macos, gcc

Below is the error I get when I do a `sudo pip install imposm`

```
    #include "tcutil.h"

             ^

    1 error generated.

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I believe that I already have `gcc` (version: 4.2.1) installed under `/usr/bin/gcc` on my Mac (OSX 10.8.5). I don't know what else needs to be done. Other details.

```
    gcc --version
    Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
    Thread model: posix
```

Edit: I already have the listed requirements (C/C++ compiler, the Python libraries and Google Protobuf) on my Mac. This is why the error baffles me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install [tokyo-cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/), which imposm uses for caching.

If you use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), it's simply: `brew install tokyo-cabinet`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for that module states the following:

> The PBF parser is written as a C extension and you need to have a
>   C/C++ compiler, the Python libraries and Google Protobuf.

At least, if this is the appropriate documentation for that module (http://imposm.org/docs/imposm.parser/latest/install.html#installation)

I can't really research how to install these components on a mac, but if you haven't fulfilled those requirements, that may be the reason why it's not working.

Comment: I already have those requirements (C/C++ compiler, the Python libraries and Google Protobuf) on my Mac. This is why the error baffles me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see (might want to edit the original question to add that info btw). Is there more info with that error though? It looks like it might be an C include file issue... like a problem with the include path.